# How to get values from nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

I'm new to robot and Python. I have a nested dictionary from where I need to get values but I can't access them.

```
${result} =  Get Info  from_here=location  mode=aggregate
@{keys}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${result}
${robot_dict}=    Create Dictionary
:FOR    ${key}    IN    @{keys}
    \    Set To Dictionary    ${robot_dict}    ${key}=${result['${key}']}
Log Many  ${robot_dict}
######Output from robot_dict is:
#{'Name1': 
#       {'nickname': 
#           {'Name': 'Name1', 'FirstName': 'Full', 'Boy': 
#               {'Age': 'N/A', 'Single': '0'}, 
#               'Girl': 
#               {'Height': '229057', 'Weight': 'N/A'}
#           }
#       }, 
#'Name2':{'nickname': 
#           {'Name': 'Name2', 'FirstName': 'Full', 'Boy': 
#               {'raw_pkt_count': '229059', 'Age': 'N/A'}, 
#               'Girl': 
#               {'Height': '0', 'Weight': 'N/A'}
#           }
#       }
#}
#############
```

Tried this:

```
${current_key} =  Get Dictionary Keys  ${robot_dict[Name1][nickname][Girl][Height]}       
######Error: Resolving variable '${robot_dict[Name1][nickname][Girl][Height]}' failed: KeyError: 0
```

And this:

```
${current_key} =  Get Dictionary Keys  ${robot_dict}    Name1.nickname.Girl.Height   
#######Error: Dictionary does not contain key Name1.nickname.Girl.Height
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax), you have to treat the code as if it were python. Since the keys are strings, they need to be properly quoted. Here's the relevant part from the documentation:

> 4. The expression inside the curly brackets is evaluated as a Python expression, so that the base variable name is replaced with its value.
>      If the evaluation fails because of an invalid syntax or that the
>      queried attribute does not exist, an exception is raised and the test
>      fails.

```
${current_key} =  Get Dictionary Keys  ${robot_dict['Name1']['nickname']['Girl']['Height']}
```